Special solution for Helmholtz equation on a Riemann surface
I'd like to get an explicit formula, if possible, for a solution to a  (modified) Helmholtz equation
$$\Delta_x u=|y|^2u$$
on a Riemann surface $S$ for $\sqrt{z}$. The (non compact) Riemann surface $S$ is defined in a standard way by taking two copies of $\mathbb R^2$ with cuts along  the negative real axis and gluing them together.
Denote $(x_1,x_2)=(r\cos \varphi_1,r \sin \varphi_1)$, $r\ge0$, $0\le \varphi<4\pi$, local coordinates on $S$.
Function $u$ depends on parameter $y=(y_1,y_2)\in S$. So actually $u=u(x,y)=u(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)$.
In polar coordinates
$$u=u(r_1, \varphi_1,r_2, \varphi_2).$$
There are some symmetries involved, function  $u$ is also a solution of $$\Delta_y u=|x|^2u.$$ The solution actually should be a function of variables $x_iy_j$:
$$u(x,y)=v(x_1y_1,x_1y_2,x_2y_1,x_2y_2).$$
If to take $\mathbb R^2$ instead of $S$ then the solution satisfying the requirements is $u(x,y)=e^{(x,y)}$. Since $\mathbb R^2$ is the base space of $S$ the sum of solutions on two leaves should be equal to the solution on $\mathbb R^2$:
$$ u(r_1, \varphi_1,r_2, \varphi_2) +u(r_1, \varphi_1+2\pi,r_2, \varphi_2)= e^{(x,y)}.$$
Here's a list of properties that should hold for the solution:

$\Delta_x u=|y|^2u$, $\Delta_y u=|x|^2u$ on $S\times S$ except may be the origin.
$u\not \equiv C e^{(x,y)}$.
$u(x,y)=v(x_1y_1,x_1y_2,x_2y_1,x_2y_2).$
$u(r_1, \varphi_1,r_2, \varphi_2)=u(r_1, \varphi_1-\varphi_2,r_2, 0)$.
$ u(r_1, \varphi_1,r_2, \varphi_2) +u(r_1, \varphi_1+2\pi,r_2, \varphi_2)= e^{(x,y)}$, $ u(r_1, \varphi_1,r_2, \varphi_2) +u(r_1, \varphi_1,r_2, \varphi_2+2\pi)= e^{(x,y)}.$
$u>0$ on $S\times S$.

Q. How one can approach such a problem of finding a closed in some sense form of solution  $u$?
I tried several things like taking variables from complex root $(x_1,x_2)=\sqrt{z}=(r^{1/2}\cos(\varphi/2),r^{1/2}\sin(\varphi/2))$ but didn't succeed.
Another thing I tried is to reduce $S\times S$ to a manifold of lesser dimension. Namely, function $u$ satisfies $\Delta_{x,y} u=(|x|^2|+|y|^2)u$. If to denote $s_{ij}=x_iy_j$, arguments of function  $v(s_{11},s_{12},s_{21},s_{22})$ are not independent because $s_{11}/s_{21}=s_{12}/s_{22}=x_1/x_2$. There are only three independent variables.
Since arguments $x_iy_j$ of $v$ are homogeneous, is there a way to pass from $S\times S$ to some (projective?) manifold of dimension 3?
